# Nuxt.js/Vue.js resuable modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, code-reuse, nuxt.js

My question is about core logic for the thing below

1) I have a Section Component and a Modal Component

2) In the Section Component i have an array of objects with title and description

3) In the Modal Component i have a template for the modal (im using Bulma framework for the modal)

Now, in the Section i have 7 buttons with a v-for loop to assign 'is-active' class and on each button click an individual modal opens.

Question: How do i parse data into the modal ? I want my modal to be reusable. So at the start my modal is empty at all. On button1 click i have title1 descr1, on button2 title2 descr2 and etc

My code:

Section Component:

```
<template>
<base-section name="clusters">

  <div class="section-map"> 
    <button
    class="section-btn"
    v-for="(item, index) in sectionItems"
    :key="index"
    :class="[`section-btn-num${index + 1}`, {'is-active': item.state}]"
    @click="toggleModal(item)" 
    >
      <div class="section-btn__text">
        {{ item.title }}
    </div>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal"
  v-for="(item, index) in sectionItems"
  :key="index"
  :class="{'is-active': item.state}"
  >
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-content">
  </div>
  <button 
  @click="item.state = false"
  class="modal-close is-large" 
  aria-label="close">
  </button>
</div>

</base-section>
</template>

<script>
import BaseSection from './Section';
import BaseModal from './Modal';
export default {
  components: {
    BaseSection,
    BaseModal,
  },

  methods: {
    toggleModal: (item) => {
      item.state = !item.state;
    }

  },
  data() {
    return {
      sectionItems: [
        {
          title: 'title1',
        },
        {
          title: 'title2',
          description: 'descr',
        },
        {
          title: 'title3',
          description: 'descr',
        },
        {
          title: 'title4',
          description: 'descr',
        },
        {
          title: 'title5',
          description: 'descr',
        },
        {
          title: 'title6',
          description: 'descr',
        },
        {
          title: 'title7',
          description: 'descr',
        },

      ].map(item => ({ ...item, state: false }))
    };
  }
};
</script>

<styles>
/* are skipped */
</styles>
```

Modal Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-background"></div>
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal__header">
          <slot name="modal__header">

          </slot>
        </div>

        <div class="modal__body">
          <slot name="modal__body">

          </slot>
        </div>

      </div>
      <button 
      @click="item.state = false"
      class="modal-close is-large" 
      aria-label="close">
      </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ClustersSection from './ClustersSection';
export default {
  components: {
    ClustersSection,
  },
  props: {
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already defined slots in your component you can pass data to it via [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html). E.g.

```
<your-modal-component>
  <template slot="modal__header">
    header bla bla a
  </template>
  <template slot="modal__body">
    body anything here like <p> hehe</p>
  </template>
</your-modal-component>
```